# Restoring Google Authenticator *without* 2-factor on google

Tags: android, authentication

I'm using google authenticator on an android smartphone, *to connect to services that are not linked to google*, and trying to setup a new smartphone before getting rid of the old one.

On the new phone I downloaded google authenticator, but I can't find *how to set it up without enabling 2 factor to log into my google account*. Did I miss something obvious? Every tutorial around, including those by google seem to think google authenticator is made only for logging in to Google.

Note: I have full access to my google account both on my phone and on any computer, but I am *logged out* of the service I'm using 2-factor for.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not likely to get an answer on here as this question isn't programming-related. You may get a better reception on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) though.

Comment: You're very right @MichaelDodd: I thought I was posting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that data cannot be recovered, for obvious security reasons. Users should double check with each service taht uses google authenticator.

Good practices include

- Enable 2FA with the "new" device before loosing the "old" device, or if not possible disable 2FA *on all services* for the duration of the migration
- Always keep a 2FA bypass at hand *for each service*, just in case